# Kumuluzee C10K vert.x

Tags: vert.x, kumuluzee

I need some light about vert.x and kumuluzee.

As far I've been able to figure out:

- vert.x: is a tool-kit in order to solve [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem), implementing [reactor pattern](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_reactor_and_multi_reactor).
- kumuluzee: framework for building microservices that has an [Reactive Vert.x extension](https://blog.kumuluz.com/product/developers/2017/12/17/kumuluzee-reactive-usage.html).

Can this extension be used in order to solve [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) on a kumuluzee service?

By other hand, kumuluzee is using jetty implementation in order to handle http requests. Jetty implements a servlet engine model that I don't quite figure out how it can be "merged" with vert.x core.

Answer (score 0):

The extensions runs an instance of Vert.x inside the KumuluzEE framework, so all of the Vert.x features should be available out of the box.